# Add Permutations with Unique New Categorical Variable to Dataset

Tags: r, permutation, categorical-data

I have a dataset (below) which has multiple categorical and numerical variables. There are a set of unique combinations of the categorical variables, but not all permutations are in the dataset (and don't need to be as there are no values for those combinations).

I am intending to add a categorical level to all (categorical) variables called "[no selection]" and need to create a permutation so that there is a unique combination of all of the existing permutations with said new variable.

The values for the numerical variables (only a few included in example data) should all have the value 0, though if a null value is provided I can insert that value later.

```
structure(list(`Primary Outcome` = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Laboratory-Confirmed Influenza", 
"Influenza-Like Illness", "Complications from Influenza"), class = "factor"), 
    `Virus (Sub)Type` = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 5L, 5L, 6L), levels = c("Influenza A and B", "Influenza A", 
    "Influenza B", "A(H1N1)pdm09", "A(H3N2)", "B/Yamagata", "B/Victoria", 
    "B/Wisconsin"), class = "factor"), Season = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("All Seasons", 
    "2019/20", "2011/12", "2014/15", "2018/19", "2017/18", "2013/14", 
    "2012/13", "2015/16", "2016/17", "2012", "2013", "2018", 
    "2014", "2019", "2016", "2017", "2010-2019", "2015"), class = "factor"), 
    `Meta-Analysis Model` = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("Fixed Effect Model", "Random Effects Model"
    ), class = "factor"), k = c(398, 398, 126, 126, 212, 7, 2, 
    2, 10, 10, 2), Q = c(1236.50029339945, 1236.50029339945, 
    352.741540498925, 352.741540498925, 380.231921977758, 11.3144127452121, 
    2.68421098744275, 2.68421098744275, 5.75656937709005, 5.75656937709005, 
    1.74656825505281), p = c(5.89614495232528e-87, 5.89614495232528e-87, 
    1.38614414562279e-23, 1.38614414562279e-23, 8.10697738675785e-12, 
    0.0791317973899664, 0.101347413621071, 0.101347413621071, 
    0.764012962020228, 0.764012962020228, 0.186308732770133), 
    `Vaccine Matching Status` = c("No Stratification", "No Stratification", 
    "No Stratification", "No Stratification", "No Stratification", 
    "No Stratification", "No Stratification", "No Stratification", 
    "No Stratification", "No Stratification", "No Stratification"
    ), `Risk Group` = c("General Population (Aged 5-64)", "General Population (Aged 5-64)", 
    "General Population (Aged 5-64)", "General Population (Aged 5-64)", 
    "General Population (Aged 5-64)", "General Population (Aged 5-64)", 
    "General Population (Aged 5-64)", "General Population (Aged 5-64)", 
    "General Population (Aged 5-64)", "General Population (Aged 5-64)", 
    "General Population (Aged 5-64)")), row.names = c(NA, -11L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Expand grid does not work as I do not need all the permutations for the existing variables only the existing permutations which have values and the new permutations with the new categorical level.

Any help is greatly appreciated

EDIT:
Here is an example in Excel (I have begun the manual process)

[image]

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted this out eventually:

Replicate the rows multiple times - this fortunately results in row names .1 , .2 etc

*Note row index needed

Create a match row index based on row names

Have replacements for rows based on column order (see order below)

Run the loops across dataset

```
# Convert to Power BI Filter Format:
MA.3 <- MA.2
MA.3 <- as.data.frame(MA.3)
rownames(MA.3) <- as.numeric(rownames(MA.3))

MA.3 <- MA.3[rep(1:nrow(MA.3), each = 7), ]
nrow(MA.3) # 61600
unique(rownames(MA.3))

print(names(MA.3))
# [1] "Primary Outcome"           "Measure"                   "Virus (Sub)Type"           "Season"                    "Region"                    "Meta-Analysis Model"      
# [7] "k"                         "Q"                         "p"                         "I2"                        "Vaccine Effectiveness (%)" "Lower CI"                 
# [13] "Upper CI"                  "Risk Group"                "Stratification"

MA.3 <- MA.3[c(6,5,2,1,15,14,3,
               7:13,
               4)]

print(names(MA.3))

MA.3[1:7] <- lapply(MA.3[1:7], as.character)

row_index <- c(1:110586)
Match_Row.1 <- which(str_detect(row.names(MA.3), '\\.1'))
Match_Row.2 <- which(str_detect(row.names(MA.3), '\\.2'))
Match_Row.3 <- which(str_detect(row.names(MA.3), '\\.3'))
Match_Row.4 <- which(str_detect(row.names(MA.3), '\\.4'))
Match_Row.5 <- which(str_detect(row.names(MA.3), '\\.5'))
Match_Row.6 <- which(str_detect(row.names(MA.3), '\\.6'))

Replac.1 <- c('[no selection]', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
Replac.2 <- c('[no selection]', '[no selection]', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
Replac.3 <- c('[no selection]', '[no selection]', '[no selection]', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
Replac.4 <- c('[no selection]', '[no selection]', '[no selection]', '[no selection]', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
Replac.5 <- c('[no selection]', '[no selection]', '[no selection]', '[no selection]', '[no selection]', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
Replac.6 <- c('[no selection]', '[no selection]', '[no selection]', '[no selection]', '[no selection]', '[no selection]', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

for(row_index in Match_Row.1){
  MA.3[row_index, 7:14] <- Replac.1
}
for(row_index in Match_Row.2){
  MA.3[row_index, 6:14] <- Replac.2
}
for(row_index in Match_Row.3){
  MA.3[row_index, 5:14] <- Replac.3
}
for(row_index in Match_Row.4){
  MA.3[row_index, 4:14] <- Replac.4
}
for(row_index in Match_Row.5){
  MA.3[row_index, 3:14] <- Replac.5
}
for(row_index in Match_Row.6){
  MA.3[row_index, 2:14] <- Replac.6
}
```